# backgroundworker image exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to take a screenshot and display in a picturebox from a backgroundworker.

My problem is that i get this exception: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Innerexception: `Parameter is not valid.`

Can someone explain why?

I'm using the `using()` blocks to prevent a memory leak.

```
public void DoStuff() {

    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    Bitmap b = null;

    bw.DoWork += delegate {

        Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

        using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width,
        bounds.Height,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)) {

            using(Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                x.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X,
                bounds.Y,
                0,
                0,
                bounds.Size,
                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                b = bmp;
            }
        }
    };

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate {
        pictureBox1.Image = b;
    };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can create a Bitmap on a background thread, you have to use the dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign the bitmap to a PictureBox you should not be disposing of it. Dispose only the Graphics object that was used to create it. The garbage collector will dispose the Bitmap instance when the Form containing this PictureBox is disposed.

Also I would recommend you to pass the image to RunWorkerCompleted as parameter instead of capturing it in a closure:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(
                bounds.X,
                bounds.Y,
                0,
                0,
                bounds.Size,
                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy
            );
        }
        args.Result = bmp;
    };

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)e.Result;
    };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I believe this is causing a memory leak. Each time I run this code the file consumes more and more memory. How do I dispose the "old" image before applying a new one?

Comment: You are correct. You could dispose the old instance before assigning the new one to the picture box. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hmm for some reason the memory still keeps going up. Im running this code in a timer, but I suppose that has nothing to do with the problem. Any ideas? :/ Shouldnt `bmp` be disposed as well? In the dowork method.

Comment: Since we have assigned `bmp` to `pictureBox.Image`, it should be enough to dispose `pictureBox.Image` as it is pointing to the same memory location. bmp should absolutely not be disposed in the DoWork method, otherwise you will get an exception because you cannot assign a disposed bitmap to the picturebox and display it which is what you were doing initially.

Comment: Ok, do you know any workarounds? Because my application still consumes more and more memory for each image taken. And I'm using the code above.

Comment: It happens regardless on if i assign the image to the picturebox, if thats any help

Comment: In my tests no leak occur if I dispose the old `pictureBox1.Image` before assigning a new one.

Comment: Ok, well im using your code above in a timer. Thats all. Not sure why our results vary. However, calling `GC.Collect()` after the image dispose got rid of the problem. Not sure how much it will affect the performance though

Answer (score 1):

Darin provided really good resolution. About memory flood - you might try calling GC.Collect(); after disposing of the Image, though you might experience performance problem by that.

Comment: Thank you! At least I got rid of the memory leak. Could you please elaboraty why I loose performance?

Comment: Sure. GarbageCollector is supposed to be fired every now and then to ensure we don't have to worry about memory management. The problem is, it usually fires only when the application is kind of idle. Meaning the less application does, the higher probability that GC will collect the disposed objects to finally destroy them and retrieve the memory back. Here you can read more about it: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx) As you can see, garbage collecting is not something as easy and fast as simply .Clear(), so it might take some time to accomplish that task.

Comment: While there is not much memory to check and free, and the calls to the Collect() method are not too often, I believe there is a slim chance that you might actually notice any impact on the performance. But if you try to narrow the timings between each calls, and the memory to free is not as small as single BPM image in the memory, you might notice that the application spend more time on calling and waiting for the GC to finish collecting than actually working. Afterall - in managed programming language we're not really supposed to control the memory, that's why the GC is for :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating. The problem in my case is that i run this coude 1-2 times per second. Could it be that my app never "idles", thus never firing the GB.Collect automatically?

Comment: It's not that simple. There are many rules implemented in the garbage collecting mechanism. If the memory consumed is getting really big, the GC is supposed to see that and collect any garbage that was left by your application. The problem is that it's not that easy to learn **exactly** how and when the GC will free the memory. You might check that on your own - comment the Collect() method call, run your app, leave it for some time and monitor the memory usage. I'm quite sure, that sooner or later the GC will fire.